# Sorting: custom query with orderby meta_value_num THEN by title

Tags: wp-query, sort, order, meta-query

i try to run a custom post type query to match following criteria:
sort movies first by year in descending order,
after that ("inside" the year order) by title alphabetically.

desired output:
movie title A, 2006
movie title Z, 2006
...
movie title A, 1996
movie title Z, 1996

i use the following code:

```
$wp_query = new WP_Query();
$wp_query->query( array(
'post_type' => 'movies', 
                      'distribution' => 'companyA', 
                      'meta_key' => 'year',
                      'orderby' => 'meta_value_num title',  
                      'order' => 'DESC', 
                      'posts_per_page' => -1, 
                      'post_status' => 'publish',
));
```

i tried several things but i can only get this "inverse" result:

movie title A, 1996
movie title Z, 1996
...
movie title A, 2006
movie title Z, 2006

if i change DESC, ASC it only changes the title sorting. but i need to apply it to the year and not to the title.

is it the right way to use two orderby values? or do i have to use a meta_query or custom SQL ?

thx in advance!

Here is the resulting SQL Query from `$GLOBALS['wp_query']->request`

SELECT wp_posts.*

FROM   wp_posts

       INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships

               ON ( wp_posts.id = wp_term_relationships.object_id )

       INNER JOIN wp_postmeta

               ON ( wp_posts.id = wp_postmeta.post_id )

WHERE  1 = 1

       AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ( 24 ) )

       AND wp_posts.post_type = 'movies'

       AND ( wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' )

       AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'year' )

GROUP  BY wp_posts.id

ORDER  BY wp_postmeta.meta_value + 0,

          wp_posts.post_title DESC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very crude but should sort your posts by year (meta_value) and then by title. It does depend on how the query is setup so it will only work with the query below or with similar ones.

```
function alter_order_wpse_103181($order,$qry) {
  remove_filter('posts_orderby','alter_order',1,2);
  $order = explode(',',$order);
  $order = implode( ' ASC,',$order);
  return $order;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby','alter_order_wpse_103181',1,2);

$q = new WP_Query();
$q->query( array(
  'post_type' => 'movies', 
  'distribution' => 'companyA', 
  'meta_key' => 'year',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num title',  
  'order' => 'ASC', 
  'posts_per_page' => -1, 
  'post_status' => 'publish',
));
var_dump($q->request);
```

Comment: it works! thank you very much. i changed ASC to DESC though in the alter_order function to sort A to Z.

Comment: `ASC` should short A-Z; `DESC` should sort Z-A.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is not as much with `orderby` as with `order`. While `orderby` accepts multiple values and your usage seem ok, `order` *only* accepts `ASC` **or** `DESC`.

After sanitizing `order` is appended to output of `orderby` processing. If I understand the logic right that means that out of multiple `orderby` parameters, `order` will apply to last one listed.

Try reversing `orderby` to `'title meta_value_num'` so title is sorted by default and `order` applies to year instead of title.

Comment: thank you rarst. but unfortunately if i reverse the values i get a sort order just A-Z ignoring meta_value_num (guessing from the fact that it is the same order regardless if ORDER is DESC or ASC)

Comment: @kyii I am not sure what you mean by "same order regardless" ?

Comment: sorry. if i reverse as you suggested i get an A-Z order of the posts, which stays the same although i change the `order =>` parameter in the query form ASC to DESC and back. so i guess the meta_value_num is not applied. so your interesting point about the logic of the interplay of ORDER and ORDERBY is maybe somehow different? or i am doing it wrong?

Comment: @kyii not sure... I would try to dump resulting query with different combinations. However I think you would need to modify SQL in the end, this logic is too restrictive for more complex sorts.